# App still referencing previous version of assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, gac

I am having little trouble with the GAC/my application. I have been previously using Version 9.0.2.3951 for iAnywhere.Data.AsaClient assembly reference but now I have uninstalled that by going into C:\Windows\Assembly. Currently there is version 9.0.2.3924 in the GAC but when I run application it still looking for version 9.0.2.3951 instead of 3924.

I tried going into Assembly.cs file in my project to see if it has any entry for 3951 but it doesn't even mention that, then I tried to go into App.Config file to see if it has any entry but it doesn't. I have also removed the references from the project and re-added the reference to 3924 file version.

How can I make my app to look for 3924 instead of 3951 file version.

[image: App still referencing newer version although there is no references]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code4life gave a good solution which would work in most cases. However in my case a different solution worked for me. Just to help everyone else I am adding that solution here with screen shots.

1. In VS2010 click on **Tools** and then click on **options** then **Project and Solutions** link and then click on **Build and Run** and then under **MSBuild project build output verbosity:** select Diagnostic
2. Under **MSBuild project build log file verbosity:** select Diagnostic and then press **OK**

[image: Options Screen]

"3." Press **F5** to run your project again. This time look at the **OUTPUT** window to look for **Calling assembly** section. In my case it showed me following.

[image]
The highlighted text in above image shows me that there is a policy file that is still present in the GAC which is redirecting the **3924 version** call from my application to **3951**. After looking at this I went in to **C:\Windows\Assembly** and starting looking for policy file which is causing the redirection to **uninstall** it. The screenshot is as follows, 
[image]

"4." I simply right clicked on the file and **uninstalled** the version I didn't want and ran my program again and it is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `assemblyBinding` information to your configuration, to coerce the proper binding. Something like this:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="" />
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="iAnywhere.Data.AsaClient" publicKeyToken="f222fc4333e0d400" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="9.0.2.3951-9.0.2.3951" newVersion="9.0.2.3924" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Second option: **unload** the project in question, and then choose to **edit** it (via context menu). Look for the project reference, which should look like this:

```
<Reference Include="iAnywhere.Data.AsaClient, Version=9.0.2.3951, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f222fc4333e0d400">
```

You can either delete it and regenerate it manually, or simply modify the XML entry to:

```
<Reference Include="iAnywhere.Data.AsaClient, Version=9.0.2.3924, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f222fc4333e0d400">
```

Cheers!

Comment: tried the first option but still getting the same error. Checking second option now.

Answer (score 0):

Search for all your iAnywhere.Data.AsaClient dll's and figure out what dll's are where keep

```
  open cmd.exe

  cd\

  dir iAnywhere.Data.AsaClient.dll /s
```

Check all the dll's for the version you are looking for and remove the rest from the app finding those dll's

if you find the dll that is the wrong version in the gac uninstall it from the gac if you need help knowing how to do that let me know and I can tell you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your application was compiled against a version of the assembly that it can no longer find.  Your options are:

1. Update your assembly reference and recompile your code
2. Create a binding redirect as @code4life mentions in his response